# Passing data from a subview to a parent view with protocols and delegates

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, protocols

I have been using Protocols and Delegates for a couple of weeks now and have gotten used to passing data from a subview to its parent view no problem.

However I am now trying to pass some data with protocols and delegates from a sub subview to its parent view on the navigation stack.

i.e.

```
view 0 - to here, missing view 1
-- view 1
--- view 3 - pass from here
```

however the problem being is setting up that parent view as a delegate I cannot seem to find a way to do it. I have set it like this

```
SubResultViewController *subResultViewController = [[SubResultViewController alloc] init];
        [subResultViewController setDelegate:self];
```

Then I set everything up in that subResultViewController I dont get any errors when I execute all the code how ever when I put a break point into the receiving method of the delegate in the main view where I am passing everything to it just never gets accessed..

I am hoping I can get some help with using protocols and delegates in this way (over multiple views on the navigational stack)

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with passing delegates from views is that the viewController has already been loaded once, so doing this:

```
SubResultViewController *subResultViewController = [[SubResultViewController alloc] init];
        [subResultViewController setDelegate:self];
```

is initializing a new SubResultViewController object, not the one already loaded(initialized).
You have to somehow pass the receiving viewController to the view that you want to send the message from.This is where NSNotification's come in handy. You can set your receiving view controller as a listener(observer) for the notification, then anytime a notification is posted with the same "name", any thing listening will get the message.Once I learned how to use the NotificationCenter It change how I was able to communicate between views/classes.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: okay cool I will have a look into it.. man this is a real let down with regards to protocols and delegates.. being that apple recommend them you would think it could do such a task. Thanks for your help I am going to do some reading on the nsnotifications.

Comment: It can be done, just pass the 0 viewcontroller to the 3rd view controller through your navigation  hierarchy. Or depending on how your app is set up through the Navigationcontroller viewController stack(NSArray).

Comment: I got abit lost with what you have just said there. I just tried to pop the sub subview and then pop the sub view inside the delegae I just called from the sub subview.. but that didnt work. :P

How do you pass a view controller to anotherone further down the navigation stack?

Comment: If you are pushing views onto the navigation stack, your NavigationController keeps a reference to the viewControllers. so if you start at view 0 then push view 1 and so on, you can get any of those view controllers through the Navigationcontroller's view controllers property. Try to NSLog() the stack              NSLog(@"%@",[self.navigationController.viewControllers description]);

Comment: The navigationController.viewControllers is just an array, so you can get the objectAtIndex of the view you need.

Comment: okay yup, I understand that. But how could I use that to get information around using delegates? or are you explaining something different to me.. Sorry for the hassle but I feel like my brain has gone on holiday without me atm... Because currently the problem is not navigating the views I can pop across multiple views in my nav controller, the problem is initializing a delegate protocol of a view from a main view for a view several entries deep in the stack... if you get my drift.

Comment: Well like I was saying you can't create a new SubResultViewController object you need access to the one created already so if it is the first view then SubResultViewController *srvc = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; then srvc.delegate = self;

Comment: ah right I kind of understand. so I write that in my view 0. Then when I pop the view controller and set the delegate in view 3 it will access view 0... Okay I am pretty sure I understand.. Will give it ago now to see how it works.. Thanks very much for hanging in there with me.. I have had a second wind and things are clicking abit better now. thanks for your help I will let you know how I go.

Comment: trying to find a way to get it to work. Currenlty I am setting another delegate to view 2 in my didselectrowatIndexpath method... And I think thats making it crash atm... so just trying to find a way around that.